# Crawlspider not scraping anything

Tags: python, scrapy

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
#scrapy crawl dmoz -o items.json -t json
from scrapy.http import Request
from urlparse import urlparse

from manga.items import MangaItem

class MangaHere(CrawlSpider):
    name = "mangahs"
    allowed_domains = ["mangahere.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.mangahere.com/seinen/"]
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow = ('//a[@class="next"]')), follow=True, 

        callback='parse_item'),]


#def parse(self, response):
    # get indext depth for every page
   # hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
   # next_link = hxs.select('//a[@class="next"]')
   # index_depth = int(next_link.select('preceding-sibling::a[1]/text()').extract()[0])        
    #create a request for the first page

  #  url = urlparse("http://www.mangahere.com/seinen/")
  #  yield Request(url.geturl(), callback=self.parse_item)

    #create a request for each subsequent page in the form "./seinen/x.html"
 #   for x in xrange(2, index_depth):
 #       pageURL = "http://www.mangahere.com/seinen/%s.htm" % x
 #       url = urlparse(pageURL)
  #      yield Request(url.geturl(), callback=self.parse_item)
    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        list(self.parse_item(response))

    def parse_item(self,response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//ul/li/div')
        items = []
        for site in sites:
            rating = site.select("p/span/text()").extract()      
            desc = site.select("p[2]/text()").extract()
            for i in rating: 
                for p in desc:
                    if float(i) > 4.8 and "ecchi" not in str(p):
                        item = MangaItem()
                        item['title'] = site.select("div/a/text()").extract()
                        item['link'] = site.select("div/a/@href").extract()
                        item['desc'] = site.select("p[2]/text()").extract()
                        item['rate'] = site.select("p/span/text()").extract()         

                        items.append(item)
        return items
```

The commented stuff is a method of crawling the pages without a crawlspider that someone here helped me with. But I still want to learn how to make the crawlspider work for the sake of knowing.

I get no errors but it scrapes 0 pages, I checked a lot of threads and it sounded like I had to add a `parse_start_url` for some reason but that didn't help, changing the names of the parse function didn't help either.

What is not working? Is my rule incorrect or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your rule to something like this:

```
rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow = ('/\d+.htm')), follow=True, 
    callback='parse_item'),]
```

Comment: thanks all i added a restrict path with no allow path and it seems to be working! wasted a lot of time on this one ><

Answer (score 1):

The `allow` should be the `REGEX` for the urls not the `xpath`
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.12/topics/spiders.html

If you want to use xpath then you need to use `restrict_xpath`

Answer (score 0):

Your callback in your Rule does not match the method.  CrawlSpider has a default method named parse thus `def parse(CrawlSpider)` should be changed to `def parse_item` to match your callback